# Is it possible to use my dataset for survival analysis, if so, how should I adapt it?

Tags: survival, dataset, cox-model

I'll try to summarize my situation as best as I can first.

I'm doing a project in which we're trying to do a prognostic model on a specific disease to determine the risk of an outcome happening to adults based on clinical manifestations of the disease when they're children. All of this using Cox regression. Now, my only experience with survival analysis is from a class in which datasets were already cleaned and ready for survival analysis, so I'm unsure what to do now, mainly with how to prep my data.

I have a dataset in which I have for every participant their age, gender and multiple clinical manifestations of a disease each with two variables; one binary to see if the patient has it, and the second is age at diagnostic. I also have the same for my outcome of interest.

The thing I need help with is how to prepare data that wasn't built around doing survival analysis. I thought it would be easy, but now with data in front of me, I realize I'm in over my head and I'm not even sure it's possible to do it anymore.

First, our outcome always happens when patients are older than 10, and all our predictors were supposed to happen before 10. That way, we could ensure appropriate temporality between predictors and outcome. But, it turns out that most, if not all, of our predictors have diagnostic dates after 10.

My first thought, which I'm hesitant about, was to create for each a binary variable where yes=participant diagnosed before 10, and no=not diagnosed or diagnosed after 10. Is this a proper way to do things? Am I creating some problems I'm not seeing by doing so?

My next problem is that it's an ongoing clinical database, so I don't have follow-up times, I have participants' ages and ages at diagnosis of both outcome and predictors. I think a variable for "last date of data entry" exists but wasn't given to us, so it's possible I could at least ask for this.

My problem lies in how to create the time-to-event variable. If I have the last date of entry the end part would be easy, diagnostic date of outcome for event and "Final date of data entry" for censor. But I'm still struggling with how to choose the beginning of follow-up. People were recruited at various ages and I don't have a variable for something like age or date of the beginning of follow-up. Is there a proper way to handle this situation usually?

As you can see, I'm confused and your help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: For the time-to-event variable, you need to ask yourself the question: which time to event (with diagnosis the event, evidently) do you want to model? Is it the age when the diagnosis is made? Is it the time between the predictor-collection date and the diagnosis?  Or something else? Anything in that line that respects causality if OK in principle. Answer that question first with respect to the question _you_ want to answer.